# How can i create views for the nested comment system in django platform?

Tags: django, django-views

I have set my Comment model:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments', blank=True, null=True)
    commentor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='replies')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} ---of----- {}'.format(self.body, self.commentor)
```

I have already create the views for the comments and have assigned the post and commentor value but I don't know how to create views for the replies and also don't know how to make the reply form for the nested comment system.

Anyone who can help will be thanked from the heart.